# How to check if the expected data is sent by a post or put request?

Tags: python, python-requests, mocking, requests-mock

I am using [requests-mock](https://github.com/jamielennox/requests-mock) and I am trying to figure out how to assert that the `put` request has been called correctly:

```py
def funtion_to_be_tested():
    requests.put(
        headers={'X-API-Key': 'api_key'},
        url=url,
        params={'param1': 'foo'},
        data='This is the data'
    )


def test_upload(requests_mock):
    url = 'http://example.com/upload'
    requests_mock.put(url, text='ok')
    funtion_to_be_tested()
    # how to check that `data` was `This is the data` and that `headers` contained the `X-API-Key`?
```

*Edit:* I refactored out the code to be tested to a function called `funtion_to_be_tested`

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is run through your function and then make assertions on the [request_history](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html):

Altering the example because it always takes me a while to make pytest work correctly, but it will work basically the same way:

```
import requests
import requests_mock

def funtion_to_be_tested():
    requests.put(
        headers={'X-API-Key': 'api_key'},
        url=url,
        params={'param1': 'foo'},
        data='This is the data'
    )

with requests_mock.mock() as m:
    url = 'http://example.com/upload'
    m.put(url, text='ok')
    funtion_to_be_tested()

    assert m.last_request.headers['X-API-Key'] == 'api_key'
    assert m.last_request.text == 'This is the data'
```

Comment: I solved it similarly but used the Matcher object directly, e.g.
`matcher = m.put(url, text='ok'); assert matcher.last_request.text == ...`
this was so I could check individual mocked endpoints rather than the full history. not sure your thoughts on that

Answer (score 0):

If you just want check the method being used, you can check that by verifying the sent request.

```
def test_upload(requests_mock: Any):
    url = 'http://example.com/upload'
    requests_mock.put(url, text='ok')
    r = requests.put(
        headers={'X-API-Key': 'api_key'},
        url=url,
        params={'param1': 'foo'},
        data='This is the data'
    )
    print(r.request.method)  # Prints PUT/POST 
    print(r.request.headers) # Prints your headers sent
    print(r.request.body)    # Prints your data sent
```

I have included the request headers/body in the code above in case you want to check the other parameters as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question was probably not clear enough what I want to test. I what to test if the API was called with the correct data. The handling of the request is done within the code to be tested and I have no access to the return value of `request.put`.